# Removed J-brackets

Tags: code-golf, array

For a 2 dimensional array we will call the elements in either the first row or the last column the "J-Bracket" of the array.  For example in the following array elements in the J-bracket are highlighted:

\$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{\underline 1} & \color{red}{\underline 2} & \color{red}{\underline 4} & \color{red}{\underline 8} \\
9 & 3 & 6 & \color{red}{\underline 7} \\
3 & 3 & 2 & \color{red}{\underline 9}
\end{bmatrix}
\$

The J-bracket is given in order starting from the first element of the first row and going clockwise.  The element that is in both the row and the column is not repeated.  So for the above that is:

\$
\left[1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 9\right]
\$

Your task is to take as input a 2 dimensional array of positive integers, and repeatedly remove J-brackets from it until the remaining array has no more elements.  Your output should be all the J-brackets removed in this process in the order they were removed.

The input will always be perfectly rectangular, and both dimensions will be at least 1. You may take input in any reasonable format.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[[2]] -> [[2]]
[[1,2],[3,4]] -> [[1,2,4],[3]]
[[1,2,4,8],[9,3,6,7],[3,3,2,9]] -> [[1,2,4,8,7,9],[9,3,6,2],[3,3]]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] -> [[1,2,4,6], [3,5]]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,9]] -> [[1,2,4,6,9], [3,5,7]]
```

Comment: May we output additional trailing empty lists, as long as the first few lists are the correct output?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No you should only output correct results.

Comment: Can the output be a one-dimensional list with each J-bracket separated by a non-integer number (like \$e\$ or \$\pi\$), or is that changing the output format too much?

Comment: Actually, can it be separated by 0 (not positive) as well?

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>(53)</s> 47 bytes

*Fixed and golfed 6 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)*

```hs
f((a:b):c)=(a:b++(last<$>c)):f(init<$>c)
f x=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYuxDoIwFEX3fsUbGNrwYiIgCLH@hONLh0poaCyVWIj@fQVcTIzbuefm9DrcOudiNJzr5iqaVsgV0pQ7HaZTcm6FaAy33n4GM/CSpOKgrQcJ4zxdpkcye2d9F5JBj8BDf3/ujABiAESZUrjBHjOFlGPxJbDA4yJrzLHEarvzxda/DdIBy38aqVobBiq@AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 37 bytes

```
\(m)split(m,pmin(row(m),rev(col(m))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZBNCsIwFIRx21MEREhguuh_C-op3NUspFgoGFti_bmLmwp6KD2NL8ZFUYtZZB7DzJdHzhfdXUs2dW_7tnTT-2TJldg1m6rlCo2qtlzXR7Kg1wde1Bsa6djwYwSuZmrV6urEC-4LeMBCiDFz5yzPfSmdkvJOP-TBR4BQkPSixg0l8mCoEiJFRsUYCd0BOZkg-URQKkFGIJv1DRKDUNoDEeKfoFiCUTf60zXPCRq_-2aNFwHJm2E_reusPgE)

Working on the [related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245748/find-the-j-twin) led me to this approach. Test harness taken from [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245700/67312).

In an \$m\times n\$ matrix \$A\$, each element \$A_{ij}\$ is in the \$p^\text{th}\$ J-bracket if and only if \$\min(i,n+1-j)=p\$.

R has some odd built-ins that return the matrix \$R=\text{row}(M)\$ where \$R_{ij}=i\$ and similarly for \$C=\text{col}(M)\$. Reversing the column matrix luckily performs the right operation, and we take the `p`arallel `min`imum of these matrices to obtain a matrix of J-brackets, which `split` helpfully breaks into groups of the right order.

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 11 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
⌊⌜⟜⌽○↕´∘≢⊸⊔
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oyK4oyc4p+c4oy94peL4oaVwrTiiJjiiaLiirjiipQKCuKImOKAvzHipYogRuKImD7CqCDin6gK4p+o4p+oMuKfqeKfqQrin6jin6gxLDLin6ks4p+oMyw04p+p4p+pCuKfqOKfqDEsMiw0LDjin6ks4p+oOSwzLDYsN+KfqSzin6gzLDMsMiw54p+p4p+pCuKfqQ==)

```
          ⊔  # Group the values by:
        ≢    # The shape of the matrix
      ´      # Reduce the shape by:
    ○↕       # Convert both integers to a range [0, n)
  ⟜⌽         # Reverse the right range
⌊⌜           # Minimum table
```

Comment: J translation not quite as nice: `</.~&,(<./|.)&i./@$`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>117</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

*Edit: **-<s>29</s> 31 bytes** thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe); -10 bytes thanks to [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder); another -4 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

```
f=\(M)"if"(1%in%dim(t(M)),M,list(c(M[1,],M[-1,n<-ncol(M)]),f(M[-1,-n])))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZGxCsIwEIZx7VMURcjBnyFtbS2os0s3t5hBKoGAraAVfBcXHXwofRqvrYKoxSUX_vv_L0fudNmdz9dDZeX4NrfTpcio72xfqKErh2tXiIoVQoaN21ciF5lWMMi0VCgnssy3G-4bghWNJktDRC3v3oMopsWq2rkjJwOCAhZEA1_OfK0DYzwrCvLeTQoBQkTE5c1aq5GBDrsiEcZIORgj4TNkJSUunwh2JUgZ1HqDGolOKM-BEeKfoNjA5-zoT7Z-jvj6na_HaAhInoz2017LeAA)

Recursive approach with some clever tricks by [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) and [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder).

Comment: You can save 10 bytes using [negative indexing](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZHNSsNAFIVx26cI7eZeOFnkp0kDxjfIrgthnEWJBAPeFGJERXySbtqFD6VP44lRKGpxM3fmcr5vLjO7Q7_fv94PTbh6u2zKK6lg5SCV6rxt5rLpnuS6NTE9jxU1-3i-u9k-SC3mEHmY63oeTeFdGHnVWSMVdwi7envLvNcXnfzvZxArbTP07SN5-iJgrboIwovAudh7sqaz41CEGAlSZTmKjt3UwyWnkBQrFAQz5FwTdgpl-algKkdB0ZSNRyVOSjkHlsj-FGUeAdnlP-x4nXL7mx_H-DQg_3JMj_b9OR8). I'd also suggest using `m=t(M)` to work around the `[...,drop=T]` behavior, with condition `any(dim(m)<2)`.

Comment: @Giuseppe, nice tricks, thanks!

Comment: [86 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZFLCsIwEIZx6ymKbjLwd9GHfYD1Bt2Jm5iFKMUuEqFWVMSTuNGFh9LTOLEK4gM3mWT4vy9DcjhVx-N5VRduchkV2Vjk0FktcoLJTLVYC03UKYuOmJitmJWaz32fMLWJ3XLOganQEp6ClgZKup4iahci5x1co2hPjf3agtCZntRVuWGGHR4wJOo67sCR0leKKU3t15AHHwFC4vIStd1QQQa_kBAJUgYjxLwG3EmJy7uCUzFSFjVZ3yrxU8pzoIfoqyhScJjt_WHtdcTbT96OcTcgfjiaR3t-zQ0) dunno how I missed that one.

Comment: @Giuseppe, thanks again!

Comment: That `-1` can go in the previous square brackets, and I'm not sure what the `c` is doing in the middle. Removing it gives [81 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZG9ysIwFIZx9SqKLjnwZkhbWwvWO-gguMUM8kmxQyLUiop4JS46eFF6NZ5aBflUXPJz8j5PDsnhVB6P51WVy_5llKcTkcGmlcgILnXlYi0sUafIO2LqtmJWWN4PfEKG3XLOp3_CaigDqx2kMkTtXGRaKkhnaE-N-NqCsKmdVmWxYYJxBYyJup4celr7xjBlqf0aUvARICSeXqJ1NTTQwTckRB8JgxFiHgOuJMTTfwWnYiQsarJ-rcRXKfeBHqKPosjAY7b3g62vI16-83UbdwPih6N5tOev3AA).

Comment: Also, the condition `1%in%dim(m)` is shorter than `any(dim(m)<2)` and you can move the definition of `n`. I changed the output format (hope it's acceptable, gains 1 byte), bringing it down to [76 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZHBisIwEIbZq09RFCEDfw5pa2vB-gT2treYg7gEAqZCrei7eNGDD6VPsxOrILuKl0yY_N-XITmcmuPxvG2tHF9mtpyLCr5sRUXUd7Yv1NDVwx_nhSdUWLlNK5bCaygDr-uJrJv1LpxJZQhWVFoqyNoQUee8fkH40i_axu2ZjAkK-CYaRHIaaR0b07PM955DCjESpMTlKRq6qYFO3iEpxigYzJDzmnCnIC5_FZzKUbCoy8ZBibdSngMjZC9FmUHE7OgDG64j3v7nwxg3A_K7o3u0x4f8Ag).

Comment: @RobinRyder thanks! Answering confusion about `c`: it was an artifact from converting matrix to vector. But you're right - here it's no longer needed.

Comment: @RobinRyder now you don't even need to alias `m` (maybe you never did) for [72 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZGxCsIwEIZx7VMURcjBnyFtbS2os0s3t5hBKoGAraAVfBcXHXwofRqvrYKoxSUX_vv_L0fudNmdz9dDZeX4NrfTpcio72xfqKErh2tXiIoVQoaN21ciF5lWMMi0VCgnssy3G-4bghWNJktDRC3v3oMopsWq2rkjJwOCAhZEA1_OfK0DYzwrCvLeTQoBQkTE5c1aq5GBDrsiEcZIORgj4TNkJSUunwh2JUgZ1HqDGolOKM-BEeKfoNjA5-zoT7Z-jvj6na_HaAhInoz2017LeAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```
a=input()
while[[]]<a:print a.pop(0)+map(list.pop,a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY5NDoIwFIT3PUXDBtCn4U8Eoid5aUhDSmiipcEScek53LgxXsCdJ-E2IsSN0eV8M_PeXO76ZKpaBddnWTc0p1JZuTWLM0JNc8pEJwrbtm-tKRdJH_GtVLo1jkuOldwJRMY2PNONVIbypa6147nzPdfOTh7MWwN3p-5juEKo6AqhTeYTOnYm69qfEQPGCKIPAQMMIfooiCAZSAohxLAevXCg6VcacAXxTwa4_pOeHEBv-MCmJS8)

-4 bytes thanks to @ovs

Comment: `map(list.pop,a)` saves a byte (and 4 in Python 2)

Comment: This crashes on the last test case?

Comment: @Neil I know, it ends with an error on lists which are exactly twice as high as they are wide (e.g. `[[1], [2]]`). It still gives the right output though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>ßest Friends Forever?!</sup>

```
Ḣ;Ṫ€W;ßFF?
```

A monadic Link that accepts a rectangular list of lists and yields a list of lists.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkXWD3euetS0Jtz68Hw3N/v/h9uPTnq4c8b//9HRhjpGOiY6FrE60ZY6xjpmOuZAljGQZaRjGRsLAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkXWD3euetS0Jtz68Hw3N/v/h9uPTnq4c4Zm5P//0dHRRrGxXDrR0YY6RrE60cY6JnCujomOBVDIUsdYx0zHHCxpDBS1RFevE22qY4ZdUCfaHKw@FgA).

#### How?

```
Ḣ;Ṫ€W;ßFF? - Link: list of lists, X
Ḣ          - head -> top row of X (mutates X)
   €       - for each of (the remaining rows of) X:
  Ṫ        -   tail -> last element of the row (mutates X)
 ;         - concatenate these together
    W      - wrap that list in a list -> Z
         ? - if...
        F  - ...condition: flatten (the mutated) X (falsey once empty or only empty rows)
      ß    - ...then: call this Link with (the mutated) X
       F   - ...else: flatten (the mutated) X -> an empty list
     ;     - Z concatenate that
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 44 bytes

```
{,'/(&/d)#'(-1 1*!'d:#'1*:\x)_''1(1_'|+:)\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJyr1lHX11DTT9FUVtfQNVQw1FJUT7FSVjfUsoqp0IxXVzfUMIxXr9G20oypqAUA0QcKLQ==)

Solved in my worst attempt at [find-the-j-twin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245748/find-the-j-twin).  It seems a shame to let it go to waste...

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
λ[ḣƛt;J,ḢƛṪ;x¤
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwizrtb4bijxpt0O0os4biixpvhuao7eMKkIiwiIiwiW1sxLDIsNCw4XSxbOSwzLDYsN10sWzMsMywyLDldXSJd)

### Explanation

```
λ[ḣƛt;J,ḢƛṪ;x¤
λ                 Open a lambda (for recursion)
 [                If statement (check if truthy)
  ḣ               Separate the first item, push both sides to stack
   ƛt;            Map to last item of each
      J           Join both lists
       ,          Pop and print (the J bracket)
        Ḣ         All but the first item
         ƛṪ;      Map to all but the last item of each
            x     Recurse
             ¤    Empty space (so that it won't output an empty list at the end, since stack is implicitly output)
```

Comment: You've unearthed some interesting and probably annoying bugs. We'll try to fix them lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 49 bytes

```
f=lambda a,i=0:a and[*a.pop(i),*f([*zip(*a)],~i)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY9BDoIwEEX3nqLLlowEBVFI2HiNSRdVaJwE2wbRRBcmnsMNG72Tt7EKboyuJv_9P38y17s7thtruu62b_V48ZjoolbbVamYAiqi3E9TYqBCZx0nAYHmGJzI8UAJCWcSclhcatswYmSYdZXhkQibSpU1mWrHRT5ijFFRHVTtS17CNWRaTqA5hWvrjlwI0Td1jwviVMoR4gSmEjCG5KMggYUnGcSQwvztxZ5mX2nAGaQ_GeD8T7p3ACN_YfjpCQ)

Loosely based on @pxeger's Python 2 answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 51 bytes

```
f(m)=m&&print(concat(m[1,],m[^1,#m]~))*f(m[^1,^#m])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN43TNHI1bXPV1AqKMvNKNJLz85ITSzRyow11YnVyo-MMdZRzY-s0NbWAykC8OCBXE6o1OrGgIKdSI1dB104BolvJM88qJk9JIVdBKSbPv7TESknTWgFkgY5CtC_QWCMQw1DHyNpYxyQWwtQx0bGwttAx1jHTMQcKGwNFLGNhVsBcCQA)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 47 bytes

Prompts for 2 dimensional matrix

```
m←⎕⋄⍎∊(⌊/⍴m)⍴⊂'m[1;],1↓,m[;1↓⍴m]⋄m←1 0↓0 ¯1↓m⋄'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##XYxBCoJQFEXnfxVv9guM/F@zxBUERQsQB2IYgZ8CR00jTCwliNbRpBW0lLcRu4JENLnvvnPfffE@G60PcbbbjJIszvNt0nLzWC64uDkCbr6CU4LLc9oaWCC@nLhuuKwGfK3GXL/MEMLVUZpQBZGluLhbJgy62aURCl1VkQ1i0/vZJQZUtvgr2lQoUrjUQpIUqdCksSnS5JDbM7ieuTQjH4lHU6gD4n9vfno0Ia/n7j9H0/8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[ćs©€θ«,®€¨Wg_#
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@kh78aGVj5rWnNtxaLXOoXVA1qEV4enxykCpaEMdIx0THYtYnWhLHWMdMx1zIMsYyDLSsYyNBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU3loeVR61qHdOlxK/qUlMMH/0Ufaiw@tfNS05tyOQ6t1Dq0Dsg6tCE@PV/5fe2ib/f/o6Gij2FgdhehoQx2jWJ1oYx0TOFfHRMcCKGSpY6xjpmMOljQGilqiq9eJNtUxwy6oE20OUh8LAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
[          # Loop indefinitely:
 ć         #  Extract head; pop and push first row and remainder-matrix
  s        #  Swap so the remainder-matrix is at the top
   ©       #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    €θ     #  Pop and only leave the last value of each row
      «    #  Merge it to the extracted first row
       ,   #  Pop and output this list with trailing newline
   ®       #  Push matrix `®` again
    €¨     #  Remove the last integer from each row
      W    #  Push the flattened minimum of the matrix (without popping)
       g   #  Pop and push the length of it
        _  #  If this length is 0:
         # #   Stop the infinite list
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 109 bytes

```java
m->{for(int i=0,j;;){var t=m[j=i++];for(;++j<m.length;)t.add(m[j].pop());if(t.size()>0)System.out.print(t);}}
```

Input as an array of Integer-Stacks; output prints directly to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##7VXNTgIxEL77FBNPbbY0KgqSAgkHDybqhSPhUEuBLvuXdkBxs1cfwEf0RbCwSogQDmYPJnpp0szMN983M5kJ5ULWwtFspSLpHNxLk@QnACZBbcdSaXhYfwEWqRmBIqF353M0Ee@jVLP2rfebaNsdDCGmgFObPjm4eVY6Q5MmwocWJ/5xKNEoeIAEOrCKa918nFrik4DpnLFQCJovpAXsxIOwY4JgKNZ2EQRhO@aRTiY4FRS5HI2I9xjyLM0IpcKMCXJnXjSh3TPaXzrUMU/nyDPrsQlSURQrsSaQzR8jT@CTx0ZM7KWSPnrPiWcvaakTtUNyRCaFRD/BN/tgWAbDIeM2mNA89wp6UbSD37NWLh2X7s74xBd0TXmDVVDxCwids5ISqwauzi5/oUJ2ya6rVNliddZgzWoLV/c8W39kPCqCu2KN/4L9pGAVwTX3B3b3Gmy28KYdR69KWfm95b6XFNNymZOYBqfw/voGp18tt8s84cobRKEkqinZXijQzzQvDmaIEvJJuVh9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
≔⮌ＡθＷ›θＥθυＩ⟦⁺⊟θＥ⮌θ⊟κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUy7CsIwFN39ioz3wnWwFbV0Kg7iIATXkCGUYIMhbfOonx8TxOm8zzgpP87K5jyEYF4OnnrTPmi4uyVFQCS2Yr/7TMZqBjevVdQeVmIPtVRIiMi4Ny7CVYUIgtsUgM8lxF/pf1h19d9lIRH7nIUQB2roSBdJoqOWTnQurC2soU5Kmfeb/QI) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @pxeger's Python solution.

```
≔⮌Ａθ
```

Reverse the input as Charcoal can only pop from the end of a list.

```
Ｗ›θＥθυ
```

Repeat until the input has no rows or columns.

```
Ｉ⟦⁺⊟θＥ⮌θ⊟κ
```

Remove the now last row and the last column of the remaining rows reversed back into their original order and output those values.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 69 bytes

```factor
[ [ 1 cut flip 1 short cut* rot prepend concat . flip ] until-empty ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYy9CsIwFEb3PsU3CxZsxd8HEBcXcSodQrzFYprEm1uwlD57THWQbzkcDl@jtDiOt@v5cjog0Ksnqyn8Kae3sAp4Elsy8Ewig@fWCo5ZNmLECgXW2GFKvEeJDbZfLtOKZCZMsUKVOt0LGtP6hOHhWGaxADuZbz3ZO7SzWgnyX1ajt9KaJXVeBtRRK2PiBw)

### Explanation

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a matrix as input and prints its J-brackets, one per line.

- `[ ... ] until-empty` Repeatedly call a quotation on an input until it is empty.

```
         ! { { 1 2 4 8 } { 9 3 6 7 } { 3 3 2 9 } }
1 cut    ! { { 1 2 4 8 } } { { 9 3 6 7 } { 3 3 2 9 } }
flip     ! { { 1 2 4 8 } } { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } { 7 9 } }
1 short  ! { { 1 2 4 8 } } { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } { 7 9 } } 1
cut*     ! { { 1 2 4 8 } } { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } } { { 7 9 } }
rot      ! { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } } { { 7 9 } } { { 1 2 4 8 } }
prepend  ! { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } } { { 1 2 4 8 } { 7 9 } }
concat   ! { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } } { 1 2 4 8 7 9 }
.        ! { { 9 3 } { 3 3 } { 6 2 } }
flip     ! { { 9 3 6 } { 3 3 2 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
f=->m{[m.shift+m.map(&:pop),*m*"">""?f[m]:[]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y63OjpXrzgjM61EO1cvN7FAQ82qIL9AU0crV0tJyU5JyT4tOjfWKjo2tva/QkFRZl6JgkKaXnJiTo5GdLRRbKwmF1RUKSZPiQtDhaGOUaxOtLGOCTEqdUx0LICqLXWMdcx0zMH6jIGiliTYohNtqmNGsnqdaHOwLf8B)

Takes advantage of *shift* and *pop* which modifies object in place and return what we needed.

Checking the updated *m* was a bit difficult because pop and shift may return *nil* which is *truthy* in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 91 bytes

```
(l=Length@#&@@#;Flatten@Pick[#,MapIndexed[Min[#,l-#2+1]&@@#2&,#,{2}],i]~Table~{i,Tr[1^#]})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9Ba8IwGIbv/RWFQNnYO0pbbRUJ5CQMFDx4Kx1kNc5gDaPNYRDiX@@@RTYsbJeQPN/z5k0u0p7URVrdyvHIx4eOb5R5tyfBEiHYat1Ja5URO92ea4at/HgxB/WpDvVWGwLdM8ufsubbzRMwuNw30M11L986dXUa@77OXlnjH5PRqsG2clADd5GLHakeYY09AsiQEykwo8HtSFsCEwMzLAguUaBEFfyC6PIugwUqAj/S7dLirx64Ocr7ZBkG8/9duGraVYYmytBjKBX5KDqmYq37wabi98sx5/FGTlGa7npt7PgF)

Feels too long but I couldn't find anything shorter

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>66 63</s>  59 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thank to @l4m2 (on both versions)*

Returns a list.

```javascript
f=m=>[[...m.shift(),...m.map(r=>r.pop())],...m>'0'?f(m):[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHLDoIwEEX3fgU72@RaRZSHCfghzSyIimKAEjD@Pg5VFigau@vtmTM36TW9p@2hyevbojLHU9dlcRknWiulStVe8uwmJOylTGvRxEmjalMLKcmmyXw132eilDtN1B1M1ZripApzFpnQek3kfD1SOsulY6HZ@6CLNUF72EwJhkGGGGBsWoANQn6N4MFHYHUepxHRSIAQAYcD@Nzr/ewEvYU/bjZW@gSHye0fFuh@O01a@lrWw/X/NcHm9GHq4ZcLLn/VAw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                // f is a recursive function taking
m =>               // a matrix m[]
[                  //
  [ ...m.shift(),  // extract the first row and split it
    ...m.map(r =>  // for each row r[] in m[]:
      r.pop()      //   extract the last element of r[]
    )              // end of map()
  ],               //
  ...m > '0' ?     // if there's still at least one number in m[]:
    f(m)           //   append the result of a recursive call
  :                // else:
    []             //   stop the recursion
]                  //
```

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>65 62</s>  58 bytes

Prints the results.

```javascript
f=m=>print([[m.shift()],...m].map(r=>r.pop()))|m>'0'&&f(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZAxD4IwEIV3fkUnaZOzKihiCGwuDjo4Nh2ISRWTSlMIiVF/Ox6gwSh2urz73nvNndMqLQ42M@W4CutaxTpOjM0uJRVC8@KUqZIyCZxzLblODbVxYrnJDWWM3XXiTt3RSFHN6kg4hAjhSQnk/5tMOqZlZ@BJED7Mhz0tiwzukeo9MIcQlRX4EMCyTfBRXTUpvQdCWKL25rom/6cZxAKC7/6PlABXCC7@GEE0JXLI2JS3VvyjdKTDVW7X6eFENYkTciPdmTf73ZYXJc7HTF3xkCwizT2j1x6HB6uf)

Comment: [59](https://tio.run/##jY7LDoIwEEX3fkV3tMlYIuVpAn5IMwuCVDGUEiD@PpYaFhg0dtc7Z87cR/ksx2po@unYmWs9zyrXeSEl51zz8d6oiTJwH132dMiLgfemp4yhSwsPvIuimp0l4lyZbjRtzVtzo4pKGSCSr48x4vvEQYfPxRMECFJAuCdYFy1kAYvtCyCE1E4zEBBD4nTCphniRgApJDZcwfdd8bMTyAjibbOtMkYgloz@sIBcruOuZanlPLY@zi8)

Comment: maybe failed on `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,9],[1,2]]`

Comment: Change `','` to `'0'` or any ascii 45 ~ 48 character should work.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 5.4 (93 chars)

The function **j** take a *$m* PHP [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and return the answer as a PHP array.

```php
function j($m){for(;$k=array_shift($m);$j[]=$k)foreach($m as&$z)$k[]=array_pop($z);return$j;}
```

Variant using **105 characters** :

The function **j** take a *$m* matrix and print the answer as [JavaScript Object Notation](https://www.json.org) array.

```php
function j($m){for(;$k=array_shift($m);$j[]=$k)foreach($m as&$z)$k[]=array_pop($z);echo json_encode($j);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lVLtToMwFP1Nn@Jm6QSSxqjbmAuiD1LJ0kAJZROatsTpsmfHO8Bl0xj1V2/POffc0w9d6u7hSZeaUCets5DwNB5rnkICHDi/S1MGfr/6DL7zt@wuZXzG5qjz@y2WCKAcftCzObtHyYrNWMSWffcM0dU4aVSwJSKfqmHG7NcMjC9YdOET9czij52ML7/kiPoU6IBJB4@uaOvMqaaGKqAv4b5oTBDTTSKMEW9rW6rCHfGYVjxN6CZEXoqsRAyEvaLvId0gMah1owNEYiNda9DQNvVa1lmTy4BWYXwg3al7eCJhgebCiZDsibdVFkepWreOAZU7LTMn8xDP1msgJh5tWoc0QtWoDBFVBQQnJjlrJZ6njapdEUy0sFbmMF3c4Md4hKl9rifsMuHgh6MHq6Oz3FpJvP2ZjzSmMfCqXPlfL0/ulMP1QA6E5EoG/pipv4prP4y7Dw)