# Convert J brackets back to 2-D list

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

Let's say we have a 2-D list, like the following one:

\$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{3} & \color{red}{4} \\
\color{blue}{5} & \color{blue}{6} & \color{blue}{7} & \color{red}{8} \\
\color{green}{9} & \color{green}{10} & \color{blue}{11} & \color{red}{12}
\end{bmatrix}
\$

Notice how the top row and the right column is red. For the purposes of this question, let's call this a J-bracket<sup>✝</sup>. The *2nd* J-bracket is highlighted in blue, and the 3rd J-bracket is highlighted in green. Your challenge is not to [*find* the J-brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245692), but given the J-bracket list, you need to return the original 2-D list.

In many cases, there will be more than one 2-D list possible based on the J-brackets. In this case, you can return either of the possible 2-D lists, or you can return a list of the possiblities.

Let's say you are given the list `[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4], [1,2]]`. This means the 1st J-bracket is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, the 2nd J-bracket is `[1,2,3,4]`, and the 3rd one is `[1,2]`. There are two different possible matrixes that can be created from these J-brackets:

\$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{3} & \color{red}{4} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{red}{5} \\
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{2} & \color{blue}{4} & \color{red}{6}
\end{bmatrix}
\$

OR:

\$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{3} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{red}{4} \\
\color{green}{1} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{red}{5} \\
\color{green}{2} & \color{blue}{4} & \color{red}{6}
\end{bmatrix}
\$

### Test cases

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3], [1]] => [[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,5]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4], [1,2]] => [[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
                                  OR [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,4,6]]
[[6,8,9,6,5,8,2],[1,7,4,3,2],[2,3,1]] => [[6,8,9,6,5], [1,7,4,3,8], [2,3,1,2,2]]
                                      OR [[6,8,9], [1,7,6], [2,4,5], [3,3,8], [1,2,2]]
[] => []
```

### Rules

- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

<sub>✝ The name J-bracket was robbed from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245692).</sub>

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24662/92689)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 20 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{(↓∘⍺⍪⍵,∘⍪↑∘⍺)-≢⍵}/⊆
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q9Z41Db5UceMR727HvWuetS7VQfMWfWobSJEVFP3UecioHit/qOuNgA&f=S1d41DZBIU3hUd9Ur2B/P650BfXoaEMdIx1jHRMd01gdBQgHzIiNVUeT1zGDq9AxgTLhqsx0LHQsdcyAqiyAojpAOXOgHmMwG6QBbl6sOgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

`⊆` Nest if simple (if the input is `[]`). This is necessary to deal with the empty case.
`/` Reduce the list of J-brackets from right to left with:
 `{ ... }` Takes the current matrix as ⍵ and the new J-bracket as ⍺.
 `-≢⍵` Number of rows, negated
 `( ... )` Call the tacit function with this as a right argument.
 `↑∘⍺` Take that many values from ⍺ (taking a negative amount gets values from the end)
 `⍵,∘⍪` Append to ⍵ as a column.
 `↓∘⍺⍪` Drop `-≢⍵` values from ⍺, prepend that as a row.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>33</sup> 26 bytes

```
((}.~-@#),],.({.~-@#))&.>/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYq7CsJAFET7fMWgIbkrk5u3xS7KomAlFvYpRAxi4weI@fU1GLYYOMM5r7DSfMTOIgdRwc4rFMfr@RREvjoVfm04UOWzsMl0XwaTXA4KYUZJ/ZBKaUvraUzFijpt/PDPksf9@cYIqdmwZceeW@PiM26GmNRo0KJD7xZ0oK2jvNnwAw)

A single reduction, where each iteration adds another "J layer".   Consider left and right parts like `1 2 3 4 (...) 8 9`:

- `({.~-@#)` From the tail of the left list take as many elements as are in the right list:

  ```
  3 4
  ```
- `],.` Zip with right list

  ```
  8 3
  9 4
  ```
- `(}.~-@#),` Append the remaining front elements of the left list:

  ```
  1 2
  8 3
  9 4
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 60 bytes

```
f[]=[]
f((a++b):c)=a:f c!b
[]![]=[]
(a:b)!(c:d)=(a++[c]):b!d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLbsIwEEX3/oprxMIWw4JCU7Dk7FlUXbC0RpVjiIoQNIqNKr4@tZM@NqM795yZcO/7x7LzlxCHoXVsHYtWKb9YNNoEbb1pEWQjHMsJKm8aLVUwR22L5gJr08jjkE4xwRgcPj6/4GFrOOeZlzX2b1BajDzCorunQ@qhYhGjRl3/VjNke1YK1fXnW8JcSrTIkhBXf77l46vvXt8x/nLOreiJ1rShZyZMyxi4zH9I1R@mzU@clIq2tKMqK9tcUQYv@WA95mJPn5iHbw)

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
{((,i#y),x),'(i:#*x)_y}/|:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxFijEKgDAQBPt7xYKFdxKQRI16afyJXcDeQlH/bqKC1Q47E/VgNkuxi9nElLxoUW0y71d9KhGtymzh0KBFFx4KVgjAf8OHj/O+0mPACJ/kAJfuPoVNopxZEaI41brSDYqqGFs=)

Simply aping ovs' APL solution.

Comment: Removed a stray byte

Comment: @coltim points out that I can simply recurse on the reversed argument.

Comment: @coltim Found two more.  (He's pretty good at this..)

Comment: Stray byte leaked back in.  Thanks @PyGamer0.

Comment: The convention here for giving credit for help is, instead of using comments, to update the original post and add something like "-15 bytes thanks to Coltim" right under the TIO link.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 60 bytes

```
a->matrix(if(w=#a,#a[1]+1-w),w,i,j,a[x=min(w-j+1,i)][i+j-x])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5NDoIwEIWv0sCmDa8LBBET4SJNY2aDKRHSEEzxEJ7ADYkxnsnbWH7Uzcz35r2ZzP1lqTPHkx0fFSuel76S-ftAsmyo78zATcVdERJCUrGOYukEHAxqkBqKxrTcyTqKYYRWJqrloMV640bWnq-cmCyZ7UzbewwmEbCKkxBgSqkYGyRIsdVezmIGPdW_iexnI11xiWTIsUfmI7kfwRs7v5DMPKWXS_r71Dgu_QM)

Returns the one with height ≥ width, e.g. `[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4], [1,2]] => [[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,5], [2,4,6]]`.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 62 bytes

```
a->matrix(#a,w=if(#a,#a[1]+1-#a),i,j,a[x=min(w-j+1,i)][i+j-x])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5LDoIwFLxKA5s2TBcVRFzARZrGvE1NiZiGYMBDeAI3JMZ4Jm9j-aibNzNv5k3e_eWpdYejHx-Wlc9LZ2XxrkhWDXWtG3hM6EtnJ4xJK5MoGZOAQw3SQ9m4M-9lnSg4YbRLajkYsbbcyPvTlROTFfOtO3eBRpOImOUkBJjWWmGDFBm2JshZzMRM828i_9nIVrpEchTYIw-RIqwQjF04SGc-pZcm831qHBf8AA)

Returns the one with width ≥ height, e.g. `[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4], [1,2]] => [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,4,6]]`.

---

In both case, the formula is \$output[i,j]=input[i+\min(w-i-j+1,0),j-\min(w-i-j+1,0)]\$, where \$w\$ is the width of the output matrix.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
⮌Ａ«Ｆυ⊞κ⊟ι⊞υι»Ｉ⮌υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7CsIwFIbn5ikyngPHoVWr0tGpW3ANGUKJNFiakkuX4rPHkMHp@y/wTbP2k9NLzm/nObzMbnwwMK5bioCI/GBNfRJykcIMH@LCbWARB9bUJRG3pXyZ8HaN8NQh/j2pKIacpZQ93elBPV0LO0WypRtd6FxzV9gqpfJpX34) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs in Charcoal's default one-element-per-line format. Explanation: Based on my original answer to [Find the J twin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245748) which has since been superseded by an alternative approach.

```
⮌Ａ«
```

Loop over the J-brackets in reverse order.

```
Ｆυ⊞κ⊟ι
```

Append the end elements of the bracket to the existing rows of the predefined empty array.

```
⊞υι
```

Append the remainder of the bracket to the predefined empty array.

```
»Ｉ⮌υ
```

Output the reverse of the final array.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

A `reduceRight()` with a recursive callback function.

```javascript
a=>a.reduceRight(g=(p,c,i)=>i--?g(p,[...c,a[i].pop()],i):[c,...p],[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNjsIgFIX38xQsIbnF2GqnmlQfwcQtuQuCtWKMEP9ev96CdEaNsjoXvnM4sNc3fTYn6y/Z0W2ablt3ul5oeWo2V9Osbbu78LbmHgxYUS9sli1bmpSU0oBWFqV3nguk07kyQNseQaHojDue3aGRB9fyLVdqDDkUMIEpAotDEIhCsL81GjH175TEJIqCjPjzMRTKITY58iH6aygJmsmPbLVm6iUjIcHUQ28VSqhgBiVVqOhKIPKXyCLo3h5fGCoMaEyMXBUbEEhX5KlFQBNWppLBWCTTw/Da6PlDP66@EXZ3)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> 83 bytes

```r
function(j){m[]=unsplit(j,pmin(row(m<-matrix(unlist(j),length(j))),rev(col(m))))
m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrLCsIwEADvfoXHXdiCEZ@lfknxIKHRLdlNSRMriN8eo7cZZmJx664pLqtNHBRGfEt/vWSdJ88JRpqEFWJYQLpGbinyC7J6nmtD8oPe06MSIsXhCTZ4kCq4kk9x8N8smHZHJzJbJAt7OtCRjPnxuTWb@pYv)

The `unsplit` strategy corresponding to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245749/67312).

-1 thanks to pajonk.

Comment: I was waiting for you to post it :) BTW, [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##HYrLCsIwEADvfoXHXdiCEZ@lfknxIKHRLdlNSRMriN8eo7cZZmJx664pLqtNHBRGfEt/vWSdJ88JRpqEFWJYQLpGbinyC7J6nmtD8oPe06MSIsXhCTZ4kCq4kk9x8N8smHZHJzJbJAt7OtCRjPnxuTWb@pYv)

Comment: @pajonk you shouldn't wait. Also this is annoyingly long; perhaps another approach is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 69 bytes

```
f=lambda L:L and L[-1:1]or[*zip(*zip(L[0],*f(L[1:])),L[0][-len(L):])]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVHNSsQwEMZrn2LYyyZlumx_rLVQb94KgteYQ5a2GMi2tVsFfRUvC6LvpE_jpGmXxYuX5ptvvp-Bvn_1r-Nj1x4_muLh83lsguz7timM2u8qBWVegmorKEUQ5qHsBuG_6Z5Nn1JsJfoNvWEuOUc7i8DULSs5EXIOe2q6AQzoFrqedlu-GWpVGd3WB8ZzDzR2UIDZHHqjR7aG4gbW3ANLdjO5grt7WHGr9S2_Vz2rX5RBZglOi37Q7UhTwzTnrvj4c5EIEWKEMSZ4KRHcMAEpbY84YwgkDsQklt6ZFdOTedFE_wUQoJmc0t4u_rgXyWSyIqpLMcNrTKkuo3ik3RXt4glbw-nmk9AlOFXmGklGkdHSOkkXWbocNRnjxTQbPOHi59_2Cw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ȯWṚUṭḢ;¥Ɱ¥@/ṚU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///E@vCHO2eFPty59uGORdaHlj7auO7QUgd9kNj/w@1HJz3cOeP//@hoMx0LHUsdMx1TIG0UqxNtqGOuY6JjDGYbAWnD2FgA) (The TIO comes with a footer that prints the Python repr, to ensure empty arrays are visible; but the bare link works as a function.)

This is very likely to be suboptimal, since I do four (!) reversals of arrays, but I couldn't find a better solution with Jelly's functions. There could also be a shorter way to handle `[]` than `ȯW`, and I might be able to drop the `@`. However, it feels like this challenge *really* happened to hit some weak points in Jelly, as the core of the solutions is tiny.

- The first `Ṛ` (and the `@`) gives us a right-associative reduce. There's no single-byte right-associative reduce in Jelly.
- The `@` also allows us to use `Ḣ`/`Ṫ` to pop stuff from the new J-bracket, since we can only apply monads to the left arg of dyadic chains.
- The last `Ṛ` reverses the order of the output lines. Since things popped from the J-bracket's end go to the bottom, we have build the output backwards. Also, unfortunately, there's no *prepend to* like `ṭ`, so we have to append the "rest" of the J-bracket to the bottom of the matrix (`;` would require a `W`).
- The `U`'s reverse each input and output line. `ȯWṚṭṪṭ¥Ɱ¥@/Ṛ` is *very* close to correct, but unfortunately gets the innermost J-bracket in the wrong order. I'd need to `U` or `W` it somehow to make the output correct.

```
ȯW                ȯr Wrap (replace [] with [[]])
  Ṛ               Ṛeverse order of J-brackets
   U              Upend (reverse) each J-bracket
           /      reduce lines with:
          @         (swap args: left=next J-bracket, right=matrix)
        Ɱ           Ɱap over lines of matrix:
     Ḣ                remove Ḣead (first) of J-bracket
      ;               append that to matrix line
    ṭ               ṭack (append) remaining J-bracket to matrix
            Ṛ     Ṛeverse order of lines
             U    Upend (reverse) each line
```